# Realistic reverse aging?

Tags: evolution, aliens, life

More than a few times in fiction they've had a sentient species age in reverse, as in the children look like adults and the adults like little children. My question is how could this trait be realistically beneficial to a sentient species? I'm not going to be picky about environment or biology to give maximum possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: *"My question is how could this trait be realistically beneficial to a sentient species? I'm not going to be picky about environment or biology to give maximum possibility.*"

**The body is cleaned and its functionality improves during life**

You'll have to be a little picky about biology, you can't avoid that.. I think you'll have to devise a new biology, before you'll be able to assert "realistic" benefits, or usefullness of this property in a sentient species.

As LiveInAmbeR has explained, the adult being born is labeled as "old" because its body looks old. But that also means there must be faulty DNA to start with. Your lifeform would need to purge faulty DNA, and let's assume the biology on your planet allows creatures to do that, and also repair a defect brain's functionality.

**Disadvantages when starting out**

Your body gets younger and  healthier every day. That also means, you'll have a very bad start.. one basic disadvantage is obvious: when your lifeform is born, it has a twofold handicap: not only will it be dependent, it will be a far heavier burden on the parent, not only because it is just starting and needs to be fed and educated, but also because the newborn will be in very bad shape in its first years. Would this be a "mirror-aged-human", the average child will need at least 10-15 years before it can learn anything.

The prospect of getting younger and stronger during life appeals to us, because we see so many lucky young people and many unhappy old people around us. In your reversed age world, this will turn around as well. People born recently will be pitiful, ugly, not able to do anything useful, until they reach adolescent age.

**Advantages further down the line**

What will it bring ? Well.. once they start off.. they'll enter paradise ! Faust would sell his soul for that: getting ever more agile and more eager to learn during life, growing strength, growing resilience against disease, more agile recuperation, increasing optimism and accelerate in study and gain of knowledge.

**Happy end**

At some point in life, the body will have a shrink-spurt. The merging of cells accellerates.. the brain will loose lots of connections, the wisdom and overview will evaporate, as the ability to keep a long term memory is reduced, there will be a phase of regression, it would be perceived by the people around you as dementia. But in this stage, you won't notice any problem ! Life becomes easier, everything feels fresh and new. You have creative ideas, but at some point, you'll loose your job, because you become very impolite during meetings you can't keep to procedures.

You'll find friends to play with, have fun.. you're a rich person who can afford any toys. But after some time, you shrink beyond a certain size, life in your home becomes inconvenient. You join your children in their home, they look after you and keep you from crossing the road, when there's a red light. It's a fun period, because everything you experience feels new and exciting. You live by the day, the family loves your cute appearance. But same time, your loved ones will miss the person you once were.

**Death**

When death is near, you'll be moved to a hospital, and your children should indicate to the docter what should happen next. At some point, your body will eventually be reduced to a non-viable form: a single cell, or a few cells. Your life will end inside a machine. That is an important difference with humans: about 4-5 years before you die, the doctor can predict accurately when your death will occur. Everyone's life will end very predictably. The process of shrinking through the fetal phase is painful and lots of people don't want that.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I may want to give this more thought

Comment: lol I've never had a downvoted answer marked as a solution.

Comment: Apparently some people don't like my (attempted realistic) idea about your world ? in fact I don't expect to change much, except appearance and psychology, having to do with appearance. When people get born, they are green, they are loved and cared for. When they die.. same thing, until the end comes. Guess people don't like the end ? but I feel it cannot be different in your world. People will know *exactly* when they will die.. and how.. it *must* be accepted to have a choice,, because the end will be a painful melting away to zero.

Answer (score 4):

Unless women come equip with tardis-shaped wombs, the birthing process would be... messy and probably fatal to the mother.  I don't see any evolutionary scenario where leaving a child motherless is an improvement.

Better to go with a bell-curve shaped growth chart rather than a descending triangle.  Have the child born small for easy traversal through its mother's birth canal, then allow them to grow rapidly, reaching full adult scale within their first year.  From that point on, the children can start slowly shrinking as they mature.  If the shrinking is slow enough, the female children will still be large enough to host gestation when they reach fertile maturity.  Sometime after that, they will need to become infertile as their bodies become too small to carry a fetus full term.

The cultural advantage of this growth cycle is that children become large enough to help defend the tribe much earlier, while elders require less food and resources during their maturity.  It also allows the education portion of each person's life to be postponed till midlife, as their bodies become incapable of physically hard work, when they need to find new ways to be valuable to the tribe.

Comment: If children devour their mothers and grow stronger it may be an advantage. IIRC, there are plenty of species on Earth doing fine despite being 'orphans'.

Answer (score 1):

We identify young living things by their proportions. Larger heads and eyes is what’s considered cute and infantile. The reason for that is the eyes, which don’t grow less because of the skull, otherwise it would mess with vision. Because of this we are programmed to find things like that cute, so we take care of them.

"Reverse aging" as in adults look like kids and kids like adults makes little sense except: some bird parents fake being injured and vulnerable to distract predators from their young. Now this wouldn’t work if the parents and children are side by side, you could obviously spot who the smaller one is, but regardless it’s a life or death thing.

Also since their kids have “adult” proportions the parents would be hard wired to find them cute. They’d find us quite cute, while our kids would look weird.

Comment: Eyes do grow, or my child will have eyes half the size of mine. They do grow less, which is why most features on the head are proportionally larger at a young age than adult age. Mostly this has to do not with the eyes but the brain and skull. Its hard to grow a skull larger compared to the bone in an arm.

Comment: @Demigan thanks for the info. I'll edit the answer right away.

Answer (score 0):

Biologically speaking, it would be beneficial to the organism if it were born with full reproductive capacity. I mean, biologically I have no idea how this creature would exist, so I'll leave that to someone else with more expertise! But it would massively cut costs of growth and development if an organism was born fully grown (not sure about old or past menopause) because there would be fewer chances of predation before the organism was able to reproduce. This organism's long life-history would also give them the opportunity to reproduce almost to the end of their life, since of the aging backwards. Again, not sure how this evolution process would go, but there are definitely  biological benefits. Hope this helps!